# How to change app name in App Store connect for App Store posting?

Tags: ios, xcode

My app project has an odd name and I would like to use a more readable name for App Store submission (`Display Name` in Xcode 14 has been changed to more readable name). What I did was to change name in App Store connect and now there are 2 listings for my app with the same bundle ID in App Store connect . However when I was distributing it in Xcode 14, the app name selected is still the old one (less readable one) on `submit` page and is not the more readable one. What is the right way to choose a different app name in App Store connect for App Store posting? The app hasn't be pushed to App Store yet.

Answer (score -1):

The app name can be changed in App Store connect. The uploaded build will be displayed (under TestFlight) under the listing of App Store connect by matching app's bundle ID. Author can choose which build to publish in App Store connect. The build can be uploaded in Xcode.